# An idiom for taking advantage of something which gave you the right to take advantage in the first place

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

Can someone suggest an idiom which means - taking advantage of something, which gave you the right to take advantage in the first place?

I know this isn't clear, but it's something like - Shooting a person in the head when it was that person who taught you how to use a gun. Or like misusing freedom of speech to defame your own country when its the country who has given you the right to free speech in the first place!

Comment: It is not a "misuse" of freedom of speech to criticize the government that protects that freedom of speech.  That is the _intended_ use of freedom of speech.

Comment: @DougWarren Okay our views differ from on this :P I actually meant extreme defamation and un-patriotic comments kind. Anyway it's about the idiom :D

Comment: I'd say it's "ironic"

Comment: In Portuguese we say **spit on the plate you ate from** e.g.: She used to work for me and I gave her some money to help her buy her own car, now that she's got a better job she's bragging about it to me, **she is spitting on the plate she ate from**

Comment: I found the wording of this question confusing, because the phrase "to take advantage of" has two quite different meanings. To take advantage of _someone_ has the pejorative sense of dealing with that person unfairly; whereas to take advantage of _something_ usually means simply to use it in the way it was intended to be used. See these two definitions at https://www.google.com/search?q=take+advantage+of

Comment: @DavidK Even without considering that the title is misleading. It seems to give the impression that the taking-advantage-of was approved of by whoever or whatever gave the person the ability to take that advantage.

Comment: @JAB Yes, which brings us to another ambiguity in the question. The words "... something, which gave you the right to take advantage ..." imply that the "right" (or at least ability) to "take advantage" is a gift from the "something" that you are taking advantage of. But the knowledge of how to shoot is not given to anyone by the knowledge of how to shoot, nor is free speech given (or even permitted) to anyone by free speech. When the question says "take advantage of something", it is hard to say whether the "something" is the giver or the gift.

Comment: Hi, I knew I couldn't really express what I wanted to ask. But the answer- to bite the hand that feeds you- fits what I want to ask. If you can suggest more similar idioms, then please do. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a better freedom of speech example would be, using freedom of speech and freedom of association to organise a fascist uprising?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Consider ***[bite the hand that feeds you](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bite+the+hand+that+feeds)***

> 1. to treat someone badly who has helped you in some way, often someone who has provided you with money
> 2. To repay generosity or kindness with ingratitude and injury

[The Free Dictionary]

Comment: Yes! This is probably what I couldn't recall!

Answer (score 8):

The Bible has this expression. [Proverbs 17:13](http://biblehub.com/proverbs/17-13.htm):

> English Standard Version
>
> If anyone **returns evil for good**, evil will not depart from his house.
>
> International Standard Version
>
> The person who **repays good with evil** will never see evil leave his
>   home.

Answer (score 8):

Consider,

***foul one's own nest***

> *Fig.* to harm one's own interests; to bring disadvantage upon oneself. (Alludes to a bird excreting into its own nest.) [FOD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Nest)

Sort of in the same vein but a lot more vulgar, ***crap/shit in one's own nest/[backyard](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22shit+in+your+own+backyard%22+idiom&biw=506&bih=331&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZxseCh4_LAhWChhoKHfD3A9oQ_AUIBygA&dpr=2#q=%22shit+in+your+own+backyard%22)/where one eats/sleeps*** [Oxford Reference](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199829941.001.0001/acref-9780199829941-e-41224#acref-9780199829941-eSub-30321)

Comment: Yep thanks. The vulgar ones really bring out the idea.

Answer (score 7):

From the "teacher's" point of view, consider the following idioms:

- **Give [sb] the stick to beat you with**,
- **Make a rod for your own back**,
- **Dig your own grave**,
- **Cherish a snake in your bosom**.

From the "ingrate's" point of view:

- from @BiscuitBoy, *bite the hand that feeds you*,
- from @Rathony, *returns evil for good*,
- and, applicable in some circumstances, a variant of @xxx(deleted answer) "pass the buck", **pass the hot potato**.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are describing  is generally referred to as a ***[boomerang effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boomerang_effect_(psychology))***:

> - In social psychology, the boomerang effect refers to the unintended consequences of an attempt to persuade resulting in the adoption of an opposing position instead.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: I don't see how this fits the original question, which had little to do with _persuading_ anyone to do anything, but rather someone does something to _benefit_ someone else, and the recipient of that benefit then uses it against the giver.

Answer (score 1):

[give somebody an inch and they'll take a yard](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-someone-an-inch-and-they-ll-take-a-mile) is said about someone who has been given a small amount of power or freedom to do something, and then has tried to get a lot more.